# React component is not rendering when the pages got refreshed on production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

React js component is not rendering when the pages got refreshed and inner pages on production mode But its Working in Development Mode with same Code..

I'm Using React Router V4, React js with Redux, Webpack.

```
class Router extends React.Component {
      render() {
          return (
            <Provider store={store}>
              <BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
                 <Route exact path="/chapterlist" component={chapterList} />
                 <Route exact path="/posts/:id" component={ChapterDetail} />
                  <Route  path="*" component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
              </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
          );
        }
      }
```

[Check Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEHlB.png)

Comment: try with <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} />

Can't use 'exact' path if a route has child routes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to setup the `publicPath` option in your webpack `output` section.

```
output: {
  ...
  publicPath: '/'
}
```

The error you are having is because when you use a route like `/posts/203075` and your `publicPath` is not configured then the resources can't be founded. Webpack thinks that your files are in this kind of route `/posts/styles.css`.

Comment: please share your webpack configuration.